# mysql in query for checkbox values in database

Tags: mysql, checkbox

I have stored values of checkbox in database in one field comma separated .
like animals  column has dogs;cats;elephants  . This is in a text field.

How can i use in filter for this in mysql.
i.e. select * from animaltable where animals in(cats) ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like query for that

```
select * from animaltable where animals LIKE %cats%
```

you can also check this link http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-like/